# Adding the dependentUpon attribute not working properly for .js file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to add a attribute in the .proj file to a .js file entry, so that the designer places the file beneath the corresonding file page file. For example, the designer will display Test.aspx, and beneath it will have test.aspx.cs and test.aspx.js.

Now, I have done this in an older Visual Studio such as 2010. I am wondering why it is not correctly working in Visual Studio 2013? An example o the entry is below:

```
<Content Include="Agent\Scripts\AgencySettings.aspx.js">
    <DependentUpon>Agent\Profile\AgencySettings.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

I do not see what I am doing incorrectly at the moment. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. For some reason if the file does not sit in the same directory, it cannot be nested to it. So, I had to move the .js file to be in the same directory as the .aspx file I wanted it to be nested with. That sucks, as I had done this before in prior visual studios, and was able to keep all script files in the scripts directory, but display them in the designer differently.  Anyways, that change was the solution and here is the code entry for it:

```
<Content Include="Agent\Profile\AgencySettings.aspx.js">
  <DependentUpon>AgencySettings.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

The designer now shows the following files when looking at AgencySettings.aspx and expanding the file:

```
AgencSettings.aspx
     -- agencySettings.aspx.cs
     -- agencySettings.aspx.js
```